# Remove stopWords with luxene 4.7

Tags: java, lucene

I have to delete a stopWord from a string.  I wrote a program, but it throws an exception.
The error:

> AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.

I don't understand what is wrong.

The code is:

```
 public String StopWordString(String incoming) throws IOException{

    tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47,new StringReader(incoming));

    standardFilter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenizer);
    stopFilter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, standardFilter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);

    charTermAttribute = tokenizer.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    stopFilter.reset();

    while(stopFilter.incrementToken()) { <--the error is in this line by the neatbeans
        final String token = charTermAttribute.toString().toString();
        list.add(token);
    }

    stopFilter.end();
    stopFilter.close();

    for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        str += list.get(i)+" ";
    } 

    return str;
}
```

Comment: I have declare at the top of the class the str and other and put it null for example 'str=null;'